# Get text from closest span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm looking to retrieve the text inside a HTML table that is rendered via a webgrid. The text that I want is located inside a `div` with the class `productID`. My starting reference point is in the same row but the last `td` with the class `span2`. I'm trying to use jQuery's [closest()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) method however I'm not getting any value returned.

Please see below for a section of the rendered HTML and my jQuery function:

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="span1"><div class="productID">1</div></td>
    <td class="span2">Listing</td>
    <td class="span2">Full Districtution</td>
    <td class="span2">$1,350.00</td>
    <td class="span2">2016-01-01</td>
    <td class="span2"><div title="This is my brand new title!" data-original-title="" class="priceToolTip">2016-04-30</div></td>
    <td><a href="/product/AddOrEditProduct?productID=1">Select</a></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".priceToolTip").mouseover(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("span1").find(".productID").parent().find(".productID").text();
    console.log("Closest row is: " + row);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.span1` is not the closest element of `.priceToolTip`. Use `closest("tr").find(".span1 .productID")` like following.

```
$(".priceToolTip").mouseover(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").find(".span1 .productID").text();
    console.log("Closest row is: " + row);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.closest()` method looks for a match in the ancestors. So you can use it to grab the `tr` then look for `.productID` like so:

```
var productID = $(this).closest('tr').find('.productID').text();
```

Or:

```
var productID = $(this).parent().find('.productID').text();
```

Or:

```
var productID = $(this).siblings('.span1').find('.productID').text();
```